# Kafka Sink how to map fields to db with different topic and table schema name

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am currently setting up the Kafka Sink connector with a topic name `waiting-room`, while my db schema is called `waiting_room`. So I am trying to map the topic message to the db schema but I do not see any data entering the database.
So I tried the following scenario:

1. So since the table schema is `waiting_room` I tried to add `quote.sql.identifier=ALWAYS` since it quotes table name and allow the Kafka sink to quote it so it can map to the table but I did not see `quote.sql.identifier=ALWAYS` in the Kafka sink. Does both table.schema and Kafka sink need to be quote inorder to map it or how can I map with table schema as underscore and have kafka map it
2. Then if I changed the `table.name.format=waiting-room` and have the db schema = gt.namespace."waiting-room" I do not see my kafka sink get updated but instead my table.name.format will = waiting_room and have the status of the connector as 404 not found.

Is there a way to map and have data enter to the db when topic and db name different

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Kafka Connect SMT [`RegexRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html):

```
{
    "task.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "'"$URL"'",
    "topics": "waiting-room",

    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "waiting-room",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "gt.namespace.waiting_room",

    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": true
}
```

Comment: 1)Does this mean db.schema will be left as gt.namespace.topic_name 2) If so then do we still need quote.sql.identifier: ALWAYS still to map it to quote the db 3) Will it affect the message 4) Do we still need table.name.format = topic_name if db name is topic_name 5)If my avro file contains the following field: count, WaitingType, timestamp, and the db schema have it as "count", "WaitingType" "timestamp", can kafka sink also transform for example waiting_type and have data enter the db without affecting the message

Comment: Do you happen to know if I use the transform SMT why my data doubled in the db

Comment: > why my data doubled in the db. Only if you are running two connectorts at the same time.

Comment: What about two different db for example, gt.table1 and gt.table2 same credentials? Do I just add onto the list separate it from comma or do I make separate transforms.RenameSessionField vs transforms.RenameReservationField
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838248/kafka-jdbc-sink-connector-reservation-renaming-fields-not-showing-in-connector-n